# How to define "DiffusionCoefficients" in InitializePDECoefficients that depend on ElementMarker?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Modelling a Poisson Equation on piecewise constant material,  `ElementMarkers` on the `PointElements` are used for the boundary conditions (using `InitializeBoundaryConditions`). This works fine.

In the same way I want to use markers on the `MeshElements` to determine the `DiffusionCoefficient` matrix on the specific element.

[image: mesh with marker=1 within Rectangle[{-0.5,-0.5},{0.5,0.5}]]

How can one retrieve the ElementMarkers in InitializePDECoefficients to implement a piecewise constant diffusion coefficient?

Based on the implicit region definition's inequalities, this code works:

```
pdeCoefficients = InitializePDECoefficients[
          variableData, solutionData, 
          "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{
              If[-0.5 <= x <= 0.5 && -0.5 <= y <= 0.5, 
                   {{-11, 0}, {0, -11}}, {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}] }}, 
          "DampingCoefficients" -> {{1}}]
```

The following code does run but the result is not the same. The diffusion matrix seems to be equal to the unity matrix everywhere.

```
sigma = Which[
   ElementMarker == 0, {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}, 
   ElementMarker == 1, {{-11, 0}, {0, -11}}]; 
pdeCoefficients = 
   InitializePDECoefficients[
      variableData, solutionData, 
            "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{sigma}}, 
            "DampingCoefficients" -> {{1}}]
```

What syntax options are allowed in `DiffusionCoefficients`?
Does anybody have a description on the FEM package that is more in-depth than Wolfram Reference?

Comment: There is an example in the Markers section in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) that shows that. If that does not help you'd need to clarify what exactly the issue is you are having by giving a complete code.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?

Comment: I have already been through the Marker section of the ElementMesh tutorial. This does not really help. The cause of the trouble could be identified in the meantime: 1: MeshElement, BoundaryElement and PointElement markers do not operate independently (as stipulated in the 3D example of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). So all marker values must be disjoint where 0 must be assigned to "nothing". 2: The marker value "1" is automatically assigned to BoundaryElements denoting outer boundaries. This is not documented anywhere...

Comment: Could you tell me which paragraph does `stipulate` this for you. Then I could try to improve that. Also I am not sure I can follow you when you say `that markers must be disjoint`. There is no automatic marker assignment on boundaries except during the conversion from the boundary mesh to the full mesh. Also, I am not sure I understand how that relates to the question you posted here. If you could help understand that a bit better I could improve the documentation for future use if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do that:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 
        4}, {4, 1}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{1/2, 1/4}, 2}, {{1/2, 3/4}, 1}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05];
Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]
 ]
```

[image]

And then:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData["Space" -> nr];
sigma = Which[ElementMarker == 1, {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}, 
   ElementMarker == 2, {{-11, 0}, {0, -11}}];
ipde = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{sigma}}, 
   "LoadCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
ibcs = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., y == 0]}}];
md = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[ipde, md, sd];
dbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[ibcs, md, sd];
{l, s, d, m} = dpde["SystemMatrices"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s}, dbcs]
res = LinearSolve[s, l];
ifun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, res];
Plot3D[ifun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]

Looks good to me.

*Update*

In summary `DirichletCondition` boundary look at markers in PointElements, `NeumanValue` and `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` look at markers in Boundary Elements and the PDE coeffcients look at markers in mesh elements.

Comment: So in summary Dirichlet boundary look at PointElement markers, Neumanvalues look at Boundary Elements markers and the PDE coeffcients look at RegionMarkers? That wasn't obvious at all to me.

Comment: @Fortsaint, yes that's correct. I added a section to the documentation of the [Element Mesh Generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) that explains that better and will become available in the next release (V11.1). I hope that clarifies things. If you find other FEM stuff that's not clear please don't hesitate to ping me about it and I'll see what I can do.